# Unable to import python Rasterio package even though it is installed

Tags: python, raster, gdal, installation, rasterio

I am trying to use the python package `Rasterio` for raster analysis within Jupyter Notebook.

However, when I run `import rasterio` I receive the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-350e27267e59> in <module>
----> 1 import rasterio

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in <module>
     15 from pathlib import Path
     16 
---> 17 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     18 from rasterio.drivers import driver_from_extension, is_blacklisted
     19 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I was unsure if `rasterio` was even installed, and so I opened `Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)` and ran: `conda list rasterio`

This produced the following:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
rasterio                  1.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
```

And so it looks like `rasterio` is installed.

Why then am I unable to import this package into Jupyter Notebook?

I know that with some of these packages there are key dependencies, such as `gdal`, and so I checked to make sure `gdal` is correctly installed by running in `Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)`: `conda list gdal`

This returned:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
gdal                      3.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
libgdal                   2.3.3                h10f50ba_0
```

Which looks like the package is installed. And then running `from osgeo import gdal` in Jupyter Notebook imported the package successfully.

Comment: Your output suggests you used pip to install it-- I'd start a fresh environment and install packages via conda only.  The `conda-forge` channel is great for gis/scientific packages.  If I remember correctly, `conda create -n new_environment_name -c conda-forge rasterio`

Comment: Ok I tried running your suggestion: `conda create -n new_environment_name -c conda-forge rasterio` in Anaconda Prompt, and I see `rasterio` downloaded successfully. I saw `Downloading and Extracting Packages` all go to 100% and then `Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate new_environment_name
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate` with no error message. Still, `import rasterio` results in the same error message as before in Jupter Notebook.

Comment: You need to activate the environment using `conda activate new_environment_name` and then open jupyter notebook. Now use `import rasterio`

Comment: I just tried this, and while running `conda activate new_environment_name` in Anaconda Prompt let me access the environment fine, subsequently opening Jupyter Notebook and then running `import rasterio` yielded the following error (shortened because its too long to show here): `ImportError...15 from pathlib import Path
     16 
---> 17 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     18 from rasterio.drivers import driver_from_extension, is_blacklisted
     19 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: I'd rule out jupyter first; activate with `conda activate new_environment_name`, run `python` to get an interactive interpreter on the command line, then see if you can `import rasterio` from there

Comment: That worked! So it seems like `rasterio` downloaded fine. But how do I go from my successful `import rasterio` within `new_environment_name` within `Anaconda Prompt` to a successful `import rasterio` within Jupyter Notebook? I tried `import rasterio` afterwards in Jupyter Notebook which gave me the same `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` error, so I am thinking there must be some step in between that I am missing to reference the prior successful import.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when trying to import `rasterio` from a jupyter notebook on VSCode, using a properly installed and activated `conda` environment.

When I tried [mikewatt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64255/mikewatt) 's solution on the comments above and imported `rasterio` on a interactive interpreter session on the terminal, it gave me this error instead:

```
>>> import rasterio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VirtualEcology\.conda\envs\sepadem\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from rasterio._version import gdal_version, get_geos_version, get_proj_version
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _version: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I then tried to manually import gdal first using `import osgeo`, and after that using `import rasterio` worked with no errors on the terminal. First importing `osgeo` and then `rasterio` also solved the issue on my VScode jupyter notebook.